# Explanation of this "bad programming habit"?

Tags: oop

I'm learning OOP and I found that there is a bad programming habit of creating
wrapper classes for information on one side and classes with methods that handle the first on the other, but I don't understand this concept so I'm asking for some explanation and an example if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should show some specific examples, it's impossible to answer this without any context.

Comment: Smoking is generally a bad programmer habit but what do I know, I am on PHP....

Comment: perhaps the suggestion here is that these should be one class - that the class that acts on the information should also store it.  if you don't have an example to provide perhaps you can at least link to where you found this advice?

Answer (score 2):

I think you seem to be getting at situations where the methods would be better off inside the information class - that the two should be merged and class that acts on the information should also store it.

```
class CoordinatePair
{
      float x, y;

      public Coordinate(float xIn, float yIn) {x = xIn; y = yIn;} 

      public getX() {return x;}
      public getY() {return y;}
 }

class CoordinateTools
{
      public CoordinatePair add(Coordinate a, Coordinate b)
      {
         return new CoordinatePair(a.getX() + b.getX(), a.getY() + b.getY());
      }

      public float dotProduct(Coordinate a, Coordinate b)
      {
         returna a.getX() * b.getX() + a.getY() * b.getY());
      }
}
```

Could be better done with:  (or alternatively overloaded operators, at the very least a static tools class)

```
class CoordinatePair
{
      float x, y;

      public Coordinate(float xIn, float yIn) {x = xIn; y = yIn;} 

      public getX() {return x;}
      public getY() {return y;}

      public CoordinatePair sumWith(CoordinatePair other) {//body}

      public float dotProductWith(CoordinatePair otheR) {//body}

 }
```

This example is kind of trivial but you hopefully could see it getting worse with more involved stuff.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a "dumb model", and it's a pretty minor problem. Keep your eyes out for code that hits every field on your information classes, or starts reaching into its datastructures to change or read them -  especially if you find yourself doing similar operations in multiple parts of the application. When you catch any of those, try moving that work into methods on the information classes.

A good way to track the second type of problem is the one dot rule - if you find yourself calling methods of a class inside another class, the first class should probably handle the operation in a method.

Comment: I like the name "dumb model", hadn't heard it before

Answer (score 1):

I would say: it depends.

There are some situations, where separating data from behaviors will be the best solution, for example in [data transfer objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) or in [domain entities](http://libis.mak.ac.ug:8000/bc4jdoc/bc_awhatisaneo.htm). This separation is also useful when designing algorithms - have a look at [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or how [STL algoritms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) are designed.

Generally, [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is important here. If your object is trying to do a lot of different, logically independent operations, separating those operations from the data can be a good solution.